# Xcode 10 update issue with Alamofire objectmapper

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, xcode10

I updated my iOS version to 12.0.1, when I run my code in Xcode version 10 getting errors like  > Invalid redeclaration of '<-' (Alamofire objectmapper). 
when I go back to Xcode version 9.4 it works fine with swift 3.3 but it not running in my updated version 12.0.1 iOS, it showing error like "This iPhone 6s is running iOS 12.0.1 (16A404), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode." Please respond. Thanks in advance

Comment: for ios 12 or above will work only on xcode10 if you want then need to upgrade almofire latest version of it.

Comment: Thanks for responding , i upgrade the latest one still get Invalid redeclaration of '<-',

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `pod update AlamofireObjectMapper` in Xcode 10. iOS 12 and higher are only built by Xcode 10. You must use Xcode 10 and update AlamofireObjectMapper to the newest version.
Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

Copy the entire line below and update podfile. Should be good

```
pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper', '~> 5.0'
```